# Delphi Twain and Scanner Status

Tags: delphi, twain

I'm trying to get some basic information about my scanner using `DelphiTwain` [(http://delphitwain.sourceforge.net/)](http://delphitwain.sourceforge.net/) -- Getting the scanner name and producer was pretty easy but I have to get the scanner status and can't find a way ...

I'd like to know if the scanner is
Online, Offline (turned of or detached) ... and if possible, if its scanning or in error status.

Thanks for any help

```
procedure TForm1.Scan();
var i: Integer;
    Item: TListItem;
begin
    ListView1.Items.Clear;
    Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := TRUE;
    for i := 0 to Twain.SourceCount - 1 do
    begin
      if (i=0) then
          ListView1.Visible := true;
      Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
      ListView1.Items[i].Caption := Twain.Source[i].ProductName;
      With Item.SubItems do
      begin
         Add(Twain.Source[i].Manufacturer);
         Add(Twain.Source[i].VersionInfo);
         Add(Twain.Source[i].ProductFamily);
      end;
    end;
    Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := FALSE;
end;
```

Comment: if you post code reflecting what you've tried, it will be easier for people to provide specific suggestions.

Comment: I don't think TWAIN sources have a status. if they're showing up in the status list, you have to try to use them and find out that way, if they work or not. Maybe WIA's APIs are more advanced.

Comment: As far as I know there is a CAP_DEVICEONLINE that should at least partially help ... but I have no idea on how to query the printer for this value. I still didn't understand what kind of params it's looking for and how to get data back! Any tip? As far as WIA's api you know how to integrate/call it in Delphi?

Comment: I never had much result getting any status other than enumerating the devices, which is a long, and annoying process.  In the process of enumerating devices (which will get you your CAP_DEVICEONLINE), I experienced so many glitches that I can not honestly recommend you try it yourself. One of the glitches is that the app that I launched lost its Z-Order because some Fujitsu scanner app tray icon window stole its focus.

Comment: TWAIN can't know the status of the scanner without acturally trying to open the source. And if it failed, the driver may not return a message back to TWAIN. So CAP_DEVICEONLINE is not very helpful